# Conflicted dependencies : how to choose?

Tags: java, maven

Let's take as example a project A with its dependencies (including the transitive dependencies). If I look the dependency tree, I see that at the end on one path, I have slf4j-api:1.6.4 and at the end of another path, I have slf4j:1.6.1.

Which dependency I have to choose? If I choose slf4j:1.6.4, I don't have version 1.6.1 on my classpath, and how can I know if version 1.6.4 will be compatible with the code that uses version 1.6.1?

I don't understand because at the end I only have one slf4j version on my classpath.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old problem known as "Jar Hell", related to "DLL Hell" in C/C++.

In the case of transitive dependencies you cannot control the versioning and you have no guarantee that differing versions will be compatible.  In the simple case of minor version changes in a logger, chances are good that they will be compatible.  But, in the general case you will run into conflicts.

[OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) was developed in part to solve this problem.  Personally I use the [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html) OSGi implementation.

The problem stems from the Java ClassLoader.  It cannot load two classes with the same package and class name, meaning it cannot load both versions of slf4j to satisfy your constraints.

OSGi is a Runtime framework that runs on top of the JVM.  Rather than running your Jar directly on the JVM using the default classloader, you run your Jar within an OSGi instance.
This requires some addition metadata in your Jar's manifest file, and these Jars are called Bundles.
OSGi gives each bundle its own ClassLoader, allowing a separation of transitive dependencies.  Each of your dependencies would be separate bundles and able to load the version of slf4j within their Bundle's isolated ClassLoader without naming collisions.

Comment: I disagree. Maven avoids "jar hell" by ensuring only one jar is present on the classpath. The Maven document states how you can have control over those versions by stating version ranges. In practice I never use this feature.

Comment: OSGi is a great technology, but it addresses deployment dependency management. The question posed deals with **built time** dependency management, specifically using Maven.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Ensuring that only one jar is present on the classpath helps me in part. If one part of the code use specific API present on version 1.0 (and not on 2.0) and another part of the code uses specific API present on version 2.0 (and not on 1.0), how can it work?

Comment: I've described this scenario in my answer (as opposed to this comment). Hopefully Version 2.0 is backwardly compatible, in which case you're ok...However....If your code, accessing version 1.0, is using a deprecated API method (removed in version 2.0) then you're in trouble.... You now have two parts of your codebase dependent on two incompatible versions of the same maven module... The best you can hope for is that you control the source code and can upgrade to the latest version.... In conclusion, this is not Maven's fault, it's 3rd party module management :-)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor "In conclusion, this is not Maven's fault, it's 3rd party module management"

Exactly, and that's what OSGi provides.

Comment: OSGi will not solve compile issues.... Don't get me wrong cool technology, but only applies to run-time deployment. Additionally the tools for building OSGi bundles are still maturing and OSGi containers are far from widely accepted. IMHO unless Oracle adopt the standard it will remain isolated in Eclipse-land.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks! In my case, it concerns 3rd party libraries (so I don't have control on the code), how to know if there are compatibility problems without seeing the code?

Comment: The easiest test is "does it compile". This will certainly address potential issues with deprecated APIs. Run-time conpatibilites are more challenging (In Java some libraries are only linked at run-time). The remedy there is a comprehensive set of unit and/or functional tests.

Comment: I would at least give dependency management w/ Maven a try before resorting to having 2 versions of the same dependency present at once via OSGi.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is designed to manage these kind of transitive dependencies, and ensure only one version of the jar is present on the classpath.

## How to see what Maven is doing

The [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) plugin will demonstrate what is Maven is doing on your behalf (trawling down thru the various POMs and determining who else has declared a dependency against the same modules).

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

Normally the latest version of a module is chosen, this makes sense as some modules might be using methods only available in the latest version of a logging library, for example. In practice it is generally the removal of deprecated methods that causes compilation problems, when dependent code has not been kept in lock-step...

## How to tell Maven what to do

If you want to have more control over the version chosen then you need to specify a dependency version range as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>[3.8,4.0)</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Functionality is described here:

- [Maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html)
- [Maven wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution)

Hope this helps.